# React Native Navigator/NavigatorIOS: Does a large route stack affect performance?

Tags: ios, navigation, react-native

I've been tinkering around with the react native navigators for a while now. I tend to find that in my app I can have a route stack that easily reaches 10 or 20.

I have two questions:

1. Does a large route stack have a significant effect on app performance? (By route stack I mean routes that have been passed to the Navigator and rendered)
2. I switched from Navigator to NavigatorIOS because I found that the transition animations were pretty choppy on Navigator when I was debugging my app. Now, when I use NavigatorIOS the transition animations are fast, but when I tap a button to change route it can take up to a few seconds to actually begin the transition. Does anyone have any experience using Navigators in production apps? Did your transitions speed up when you created the production version?

I'm currently just developing my app for an ios release, with an android release to come later.